# How to open specific global port with boost asio for upnp

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, upnp

When i open port with this on my PC:

```
ip::udp::socket socket{ service, { ip::udp::v4(), 4205 } };
```

and send message to server from my PC, the local and global opened ports are equal.

[equal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX97r.jpg)

But, when my friend open client app, he has different local and global port.

[different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtUEk.jpg)

I create upnp with the same external and internal ports. And i need equal port. upnp external port, and opened external port.

How to use upnp, if i can't open specific external port?!

client:

```
upnp::upnp_wrapper upnp{};
upnp.redirect(upnp::internal_port{ 42053 }, 
              upnp::external_port{ 42053 }, 
              upnp::eProtocol::UDP, "Description");

io_service service;
ip::udp::socket socket{ service, { ip::udp::v4(), 42053 } };

ip::udp::endpoint server_ep{ ip::address::from_string("100.71.188.14"s), 9999u };

socket.connect(server_ep);

std::cout << "local_endpoint: " << socket.local_endpoint().address().to_string() << ':' << socket.local_endpoint().port() << '\n';

std::cout << "remote_endpoint: " << socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << ':' << socket.remote_endpoint().port() << '\n';

cout << "send request\n";
socket.send(buffer("local_endpoint: " + socket.local_endpoint().address().to_string() + ':' + std::to_string(socket.local_endpoint().port()) + '\n' +
    "remote_endpoint: " + socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() + ':' + std::to_string(socket.remote_endpoint().port()) + '\n'));
cout << "request sent\n\n";

array<char, 60> buff = {};
cout << "wait answer\n";
auto answer_length = socket.receive(buffer(buff));
cout << "answer recived: ";
cout.write(buff.data(), answer_length);

cout << "\nsend goodd\n";
socket.send(buffer("GOOOOD"s));


cout << "\n\nEND";
cin.get();`
```

server:

```
io_service service;
ip::udp::socket socket{ service };
socket.open(ip::udp::v4());
socket.bind(ip::udp::endpoint{ ip::udp::v4(), 9999u });
ip::udp::endpoint client_ep;

array<char, 100> buff = {};
cout << "start recive\n";
auto recived_length = socket.receive_from(buffer(buff), client_ep);
cout << "message recived from: " + client_ep.address().to_string() + ':' + to_string(client_ep.port()) + "\n-> ";
std::cout.write(buff.data(), recived_length);

cout << "\n\nsend answer\n";
socket.send_to(buffer("ANSWER"s), client_ep);
cout << "answer sent\n";

cout << "start good\n";
 recived_length = socket.receive_from(buffer(buff), client_ep);
std::cout.write(buff.data(), recived_length);

cout << "\nEND";
cin.get();
```

Comment: There's no error handling in the example, how can you tell the upnp::redirect() call succeeded? It could e.g. be telling you it can't assign the external port because it's already in use...

Comment: i have watched in router settings of my friend. Upnp is success installed. But client still can't receive data form server. (but if i running client with server on my PC there is all good) Please. I want to now WHY.

Comment: As I already said, look at the return values and error messages. _If_ the call succeeds but you can see from router logs that the newly opened port is not what you asked for, then you know the router is making a mistake (and can maybe workaround). Before that you're just guessing.